# How to teplace each iteration of a pattern within a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to replace each iteration of a pattern within a string with =REPLACED and done one at a time.

replace.py

```
import re
a = "http://www.blah.com/?=wah?=stuff.something" # String being worked on
b = "=" # Pattern to find

z = a # Create a copy of a

x = "REPLACED" # Thing to replace with

if b not in z:
    print("NOT FOUND")
else:
    start_indc = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('(?=' + b + ')', a)] # Find the location for each pattern found.
    for m in range(len(start_indc)):
        print(f"A:{a}")
        print(f"X:{x}")
        print(f"B:{b}")
        print(f"Z:{z}")

        z = re.sub(b, b + x, z) # Here is the replacement

        print(f"A:{a}")
        print(f"X:{x}")
        print(f"B:{b}")
        print(f"Z:{z}")

        print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
        del z # Flush z
        z = a # Set z to a
```

The expected result should be:
http://www.blah.com/?=REPLACEDwah?=stuff.something
http://www.blah.com/?=wah?=REPLACEDstuff.something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`z = re.sub(b, b + x, z)` will replace **all** occurrences in the string. Although we can make it replace only one occurrence by passing `count=1` to the `re.sub` method, it will only replace the first occurrence. Therefore, we need to do the replacement ourselves:

```
import re

string = "http://www.blah.com/?=wah?=stuff.something" # String being worked on
pattern = "=" # Pattern to find

replacement = "=REPLACED" # Thing to replace with

if pattern not in string:
    print("NOT FOUND")
else:
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, string):
        start = match.start()
        end = match.end()
        # Since strings in Python are immutable, we create a new string
        # for each match
        replaced = string[:start] + replacement + string[end:]
        print(replaced)
```

Result:

```
http://www.blah.com/?=REPLACEDwah?=stuff.something
http://www.blah.com/?=wah?=REPLACEDstuff.something
```